# Android relative layout dynamic content overlaps

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Here is the layout file. The dynamic  larger content is overlapping with the LinearLayout. The issue is visible when the dynamic content contains larger text-

```
 <data>
    <variable
        name="searchItem"
        type="com.demo.search.core.viewmodels.itemviewmodels.UserSearchResultItemViewModel"/>
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_result_item_container"
    style="@style/search_result_item_container"
    android:background="@{searchItem.layoutBackground}"
    android:contentDescription="@{searchItem.contentDescription}"
    android:onClick="@{searchItem::onClick}"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <include
        android:id="@+id/user_details"
        layout="@layout/search_result_user_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        bind:searchItem="@{searchItem}"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_result_user_icons_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/user_details"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/user_details">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search_result_user_video_call_button"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_4x"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_4x"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/call_buttons_margin"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_10"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:contentDescription="@string/action_video_call"
            android:onClick="@{() -> searchItem.onVideoCallButtonClick()}"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:visibility="@{searchItem.shouldShowVideoCallButton()}"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icn_video_bluepurple"/>
  --------- has bunch of other buttons too -----------

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Could you please help?
Here is the issue image -
[image]

Comment: Is this the toolbar/appbar of your layout? Also please add the image of your whole layout

Comment: Also state what would you want as a solution. Like, would you sacrifice the font size of the text? Or would you want the icons to be displaced?

Comment: Thank you @AbhishekChoudhary for looking into! It's a search result. I am fine with shorter font. I have tried with android:elipsize too, but it was covering whole screen for larger texts with both image overlapped with text. Icons are needed.

Comment: What else did you try?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the height of the textView containing the search result programmatically. Using

   `getMeasuredHeight()` or `getHeight()`
2. Increase the maxLines your textView contains using `setMaxLines()` method

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek Choudhary! Here the text is a type of Spanned instance and has been constructed as SpannableStringBuilder. What would you recommend here?

Comment: I'm not so much known about SpannableStringBuilder but check if you can use an if statement to check whether or not the text to be displayed too long to be fit in the layout then you can act accordingly as I said in my answer